# Cannot access GIMP help because AppArmor stops it

Tags: gimp, apparmor, default-browser

I just installed GIMP through Ubuntu Software, which I understand uses snap. I tried to access GIMP help but it was blocked. I got this error:

`Could not open 'https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-help.xml' for reading: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.108" (uid=1000 pid=7457 comm="/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/help/help -gimp 16 14 -" label="snap.gimp.gimp (enforce)") interface="org.gtk.vfs.Daemon" member="GetConnection" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.109" (uid=1000 pid=7461 comm="/usr/libexec/gvfsd-http --spawner :1.4 /org/gtk/gv" label="unconfined")`

I understand that I must `snap connect` some gimp service to some http service. How do I discover which services must be connected?

Comment: gimp-help can easily be installed to read locally. As well, the xml file you reference is almost impossible to read. Although your question asks about apparmor, I shall propose an answer to read the help on your own computer.  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you install gimp-help:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp-help-common gimp-help-en
```

Substitute your language preference if not en for English.

Now you can read the help locally with:

```
firefox /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/gimp-help.xml
```

You may click the links to proceed to the desired help sections.

Comment: Adding `snap remove gimp` and then `sudo apt-get install gimp` will be reasonable.

Comment: @chili555 answer does not work. The issue is the protections put in by snap.

Comment: @N0rbert 's suggestion works. I can now access context sensitive help from within GIMP. Alas, my understanding of snap is not improved.

Comment: When I try chili555's advice above, I get this Firefox error: `Firefox can’t find the file at /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/gimp-help.xml.` This has something to do with AppArmor blocking calls to the external Gimp Help web site. I do not understand why the local Helpfiles are also blocked.

Comment: Please try .html instead of .xml and tell us if it worked.